# Creating ExtJS tree from a non-NodeInterface formatted data

Tags: extjs4, treepanel

I am looking for a way to load an ExtJS 4.0 Tree panel from a local data store.  The data within the store does not contain any NodeInterface elements (e.g. children, leaf etc).  This is done so that a single data store could be used against multiple views (such as Tree, Grid, a GoogleMap etc).  However, the Tree panel uses a TreeStore which requires the data to have NodeInterface-specific elements.  Is there a way to achieve this?  I can think of building the tree dynamically by using the NodeInterface methods starting from the root node, but not sure if it's the right way.